# change or add index type for a List in c#

Tags: c#

I have created an extension method called getByName for my List of Channel objects `List<Channel> list` where each channel has a Name. 
Is there a way to get a Channel Item by writing `list["Channel Name"]`?  rather than typing `list.getByName("Channel Name")`?

Comment: `Dictionary` is the type you are looking for. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You can derive from `List<T>` and add an indexer `this[string name]`. There is no other way to add indexers to an existing type.

Comment: `getByName` is much more readable then index. From performance point of view there no difference, unless you will use `Dictionary` in background.

Comment: Are you wanting to have an extension *property* (indexer)? If so, you cannot have it yet, but it should be possible in [C#8](https://adrientorris.github.io/csharp/what-i-get-from-the-preview-of-csharp-8-with-Mads-Torgersen.html#extension_everything).

Comment: Thanks a lot ,
yes apparently I can't have an Indexer with my Extentions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an indexer method like this

```
public Channel this[string name]
{
    get
    {
         return getByName(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks A lot ,this will work If i had to derived from List<T> first.